# How to include meta tags to React SSR route that have to wait on API call?

Tags: reactjs, meta-tags, react-helmet, facebook-debugger

I have a server-rendered React project where I'm using React-Helmet to get meta tags from client-side components to the server using Helmet.renderStatic(). I can get facebook crawler to read hard coded meta tags, but can't get meta tags that depend on API response from by backend to get read by facebook's crawlers. I depend on API response to get information like title, description, and keywords to update my meta-tags. I need to be able to share these dynamic pages on facebook. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @kedar reddy, i'm actually facing the same problem, did you found a solution ?

Comment: I'm using react-helmet-async as jsw324 suggested below. What it does is basically inject the server rendered code with meta tags specified in your components BEFORE ComponentDidMount gets called or your component gets mounted. So you can have variables in your meta tags based on your location/route for example.

Answer (score -2):

Check out `react-helmet-async` - a fork of `react-helmet` first made by the New York Times.  It was made specifically for your use case: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet-async

Comment: Thanks @jsw324 I will check it out and report back :)

Comment: while react-helmet-async helps ensure there are no meta data leaks between requests to the server, my problem of getting data before rendering a page still exists. Should I be looking into prefetching data?